# Provide alternate PyPI URL for Travis CI to install dependencies from?

Tags: python, travis-ci

I want to setup Travis CI so that it can find Python dependencies in our own PyPI server.

I know I can put the `--extra-index-url option` into the requirements.txt file, but I would have rather not hardcoded the PyPI URL in the requirements file, but rather left requirements.txt generic and specify the PyPI URL just for Travis. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [custom install commands](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#install), e.g.:

```
install: pip install -i http://d.pypi.python.org/simple -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not complete if the extra-index-url is containing a username & password and one does not want to have their credentials in the .travis.yml.

If you happen to have a private password protected pypi running you can use environment variables set on travis to store the password and refer to it in the travis.yml